# I need to use htaccess for sever solutions

Tags: .htaccess

I have three directories

phone/
email/
profile/

In the phone directory I would have for example phone/555-555-1212.html
I would like to use htaccess to call my php file and search mysql 
that page is /phone/template.php?a=555&b=555&c=1212

Email same thing
email/jay@gmail.com.html
php page /email/template.php?email=jay@gmail.com

Profile page would be 
/profile/123456.html
to call /template/profile.php?id=123456

Please help
Thanks!!

Right now in my profile folder I am practicing and have this but if I do not have anything else after the profile/ it just pulls a blank page

I am a complete rookie to htaccess and am trying to learn

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([0-9_-]+).html$ index.php?ter_id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

put this in the root's .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d


#----- Email Rewrite
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} email/([^/]+)                        [NC]
RewriteRule .* email/email_template.php?email=%1

#----- Profile Rewrite
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} profile/([^/]+)                      [NC]
RewriteRule .* profile/profile_template.php?profile=%1

#----- Phone Rewrite
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} phone/([^/]+)-([^/]+)-([^/]+)        [NC]
RewriteRule .* phone/phone_template.php?a=%1&b=%2&c=%3
```

**P.S:** *DO NOT* forget to sanitize the $_GET['foo'] in your pages and remove any unneeded symbol